# What is the intuition behind P/qpoly=P/poly?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I very much struggle to understand the qualitative differences between anything/qpoly. For exampe we read at [Watrus](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.3401.pdf) that

> BQP/qpoly essentially are the decision problems that are solved by
> polynomial time quantum algorithms with quantum advice in the natural
> way.

What is the "natural ways" here? The advice here seems to be some "given" state $\rho(n)$. When I am considering an actual quantum algorithm, is this supposed to be the initial state of a given problem? **Is there a "physical way" to understand the advice here and what the problem would look like if advice was non-existent?** That is, what is the qpoly part in BQP/qpoly and what is the poly part in BQP/poly?

Later [he goes on](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.3401.pdf) and essentially says that:

> The only reasonable interpretation of BPP/qpoly and P/qpoly is that
> classical circuits effectively measure quantum states in the standard
> basis the instant that they touch them

Again, I do struggle to understand the qualitative difference between these classes. P/qpoly seems to be more related to problems that are solved classically by a Turing machine with some quantum advice. What would that advice be for such a problem? **Is there some "physical way" or example to help towards intuition?**

Finally, why $$
\mathrm{BPP} / \text { qpoly }=\mathrm{BPP} / \text { rpoly }=\mathrm{BPP} / \text { poly }=\mathrm{P} / \text { qpoly }=\mathrm{P} / \text { rpoly }=\mathrm{P} / \text { poly}
?$$

Why, e.g., P/qpoly = P/poly?

Comment: Right after your final display, it says "The principle behind these equalities is that nonuniformity is stronger than randomness" and cites Adleman, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/poly#Bounded-error_probabilistic_polynomial_is_contained_in_P/poly You should see that proof if you haven't yet, but the idea is that one can encode the useful part of randomness into the advice string, so additional access to randomization doesn't help if you already have advice. Don't know about the first parts of your question and hope they get an answer.